# Voicemail indicator won't go away

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, voicemail

On my Atrix running 2.3.6, there is a permanent icon in my notification bar saying that I have unread voicemail. I understand that this icon is flagged on the SIM card itself: sure enough, if I pop the SIM card into another phone, the icon shows up there too.

How do I get rid of it? I've tried every suggestion on Google, which amounts to leaving myself a message and then deleting it, or calling customer service. The only kosher method of getting rid of it is to have my carrier send me the special SMS that clears the icon, which is normally sent when you listen to your messages (but it's not happening for me). Customer service reps seem to have no idea what this means so I can't get them to manually send that SMS. For what it's worth, I'm on Rogers in Canada (but my Atrix is running the AT&T build of Android).

Some versions of Android allegedly have a "Clear voicemail indicator" setting, but I have no such thing.

If it's possible through executing code on the Android, then:

- Has someone written an app to clear it from the SIM card? I can't find anything, but I can't imagine something like that would be allowed on the market since it would use hidden libraries.
- Does anyone have experience writing apps that use hidden libraries and can point me in the right direction? I've been able to follow tutorials that set up an Eclipse environment  for compiling apps that use hidden libraries, I just have no idea where to start with the SIM card stuff.

If not, then do I just have to live with it?

EDIT: Using standard carrier voicemail, not Google Voice.

Comment: Are you using Google Voice to handle your voicemail?  I had a similar issue when I got a new phone.  I got a voicemail before I finished setting up my Google Voice account on the phone.  After I got it set up I couldn't clear the VZW voicemail notification until I disabled Google Voice then went into the VZW voicemail to delete it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using standard carrier voicemail.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do what you want to do but if all else fails you could try getting a new SIM card.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's workable. I could "accidentally" drop it into Lake Ontario and then ask for a new one. Funny thing is, the notification icon was there as soon as I got the card, before I even had VM enabled on my plan :P

Answer (score 1):

Simply long press the notification and select **app info**. Then tap on **FORCE STOP**.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here with Galaxy S5 on Cricket Wireless. Turns out there was an unknown message sitting in the inbox that never showed itself as "new". Once I completely scrubbed the voicemail of all messages including the hidden one, the icon went away. It now works quite well. Doublecheck your voicemail messages.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix is to ask your carrier for a new SIM, but it would be worth reporting it to them as a problem so they can investigate it. It might be a problem at your carrier's end and they just don't know about it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a "message" sent by the network operator. I resolved it by just calling and listening the message.

Yes, this costed me money but the icon disappeared after. (Another "message" was sent by the operator telling my SIM that I have no more unlistened voice messages)

Answer (score -1):

Call yourself and leave a message. Listen to it, then erase it right after. Turn the phone off then on, it will then be gone.