# Voicemail Notification Stuck

Tags: notifications, voicemail

I'm on T-Mobile, running Android 4.1.2 on Samsung Galaxy S2.

I have had this voicemail notification stuck on my home screen for the past two days. I can't swipe it off the notification screen (can't dismiss it), and when I check my voicemails it says I have none, so I'm unsure why it's still there.

I've tried multiple times reaching my voicemail inbox, to see if that would correct it... and I've reset my phone a couple times as well and still no luck.

Anyone else having this issue, or have any idea how to get rid of it (aside from completely resetting the phone, or calling T-Mobile and having them reset it)?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: This would seem to be the same issue: [Voicemail indicator won't go away](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21811)

Comment: One of my old numbers got perma-stuck like this do to an error on the carrier's end.  The phone would check for VMs and get told there was 1 even though there wasn't.

Answer (score 5):

Long-press on the notification and you should get a little "app info" box.  Hit that, then hit "force stop".  If the app info box doesn't appear, go into Settings -> Application Manager -> All, find the Phone app, and force stop it.  That should send the notification packing.

If it comes back, the problem is T-Mobile sending out erroneous "You have voicemail" announcements and you'll have to talk to them about it.

Answer (score 3):

Try leaving yourself voicemail, then listening to it, then deleting it.  (Sounds like something I had to do a few years ago)

Comment: I've had a stuck voicemail notification for a few weeks, and restarting the phone did nothing. I confirm that this solution still works (Samsung Galaxy Note10+, Android 10, SFR operator in France).

Answer (score 0):

It went away after I restarted the phone.